# Ruby on rails 3 select box values combined ready for validation, is this possible?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, rvm

I have created a custom date_Select field using 3 separate select fields:

```
<%= f.select :day, options_for_select(User::DAYS), :include_blank => "Day:" %>
<%= f.select :month, options_for_select(User::MONTHS), :include_blank => "Month:" %>
<%= f.select :year, options_for_select(User::YEAR_RANGE), :include_blank =>"Year:" %>
```

In my User.rb (Model) I have this validation rule and also using validates_timelessness gem:

```
  MONTHS = ["January", 1], ["February", 2]..etc
  DAYS = ["01", 1], ["02", 2], ["03", 3]..etc
  START_YEAR = Time.now.year - 111
  END_YEAR = Time.now.year
  YEAR_RANGE = START_YEAR..END_YEAR

validates :birthday,   :timeliness  => {:on_or_before => lambda { Date.current }, :type => :date, :on_or_before_message => "Select a valid birthday"}
```

I have created some tests which work perfectly fine with the date_select that comes with rails but that date_select is buggy which is why I opted for a custom one. My only issue now is I wish to get day, month and year to work with my :birthday symbol. How do I combine all 3 so that my :birthday symbol can use the select data? If that makes sense...

The date_select would have been perfect but it lets users submit a form without the yea being filled out and if a users chooses 1 for a day and clicks submit it will automatically select january. I haven't found a way round that.

So I'm using 3 separate select fields which I want to combine and make work with :birthday just like date_select did.

Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i would recommend using a date-select pop-up.

There are several gems available.  I have used the one detailed in http://www.rubyinside.com/calendar-date-select-a-lightweight-prototype-based-datetime-picker-for-rails-developers-573.html with success.

Once you have a real date field you'll be in a better position to perform date type validations including ranges and presence that you can be confident in worrectly with that type of data.

Comment: I don't like the pop ups, I think they're ugly. I prefer 3 select boxes. If there was a gem around with 3 select boxes I would certainly use that.

Comment: Personal preferences and opinions about gui elements like pop-ups are interesting but unlikely to represent most general users who are comfortable using a date pop-up (for example "well I think three boxes are ugly... etc).  
That way you have a real date and can parse it to your hearts desire.  I would not mix personal preferences with currently accepted standards/usage. I myself have several preferences in design that I do NOT use commercially as most users want what they see elsewhere so they don't have to 'adjust' to a different implementation.

Answer (score 0):

The `select_date` isn't buggy, you need to perform the necessary [data validation](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html) on your end so an empty year isn't allowed. Validation is designed to let you specify what data is allowed into your app. Only you can be the gatekeeper of what is considered 'valid'.

Comment: In my eyes it is buggy if I have written all necessary tests to not allow empty dates, incorrect dates etc and done this even before I added the date_Select to my form. I tested extensively so I know for a fact I've not allowed blank dates. A date such as 1102 would fail because it's missing the year. 19801102 would pass.

Comment: By your definition, "1102" is an invalid date. If your validations allow this date to be written to the database, then your validations are, by definition, not validating correctly - that's their job. All you would need to do is write a validation requiring an 8-digit date value "yyyymmdd" (assuming the sample values you gave above are the values you get back from the select_date). It's the model's responsibility to make sure data is valid, not the UI control. Something like `validate :date_includes_year`

Comment: use 'other eyes' to broaden your horizon and you'll use 'in my eyes' less